# How to log a Database call in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, interceptor

I have Spring Boot application which calls multiple Database I need to log certain values before and after DB call along with time.What is the best effective design for this use case.One of the implementation is using AOP around advice but does it have performance over head beacause of Proxy class?Is there any other custome implementation like using of interceptors/listners for this use case with example.

Comment: Please present a code-centric problem which can have a correct answer. Questions most likely resulting in opinionated answers are not wanted at SO. Who decides what is the "best effective design"? And how is "effective" defined in your mind anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Similar logging question is part of [FAQ in Spring Data JPA docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_common). They are suggesting to use AOP for such logging, so it is preferred way.